# Minimum hardware requirements of server for host ArcGIS Server / QGIS / GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, server, cache, hosting

I want to buy server on (Hetzner or other) for host the OpenLayers map on site. Well, I do not understand what the performance should be the server.

I know that it depends on many factors (size, format, cache and etc), but how can I calculate it?

For example.

- 20 GB data TIFF, cache 3GB png

And what other factors should I consider?

I think the use of a ArcGIS server, QGIS or other doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "host the OpenLayers map on site" isn't much clear as using OpenLayers is more a client side topic: OpenLayers is a JavaScript library and works on the browser.

Using OpenLayers doesn't depend in any way on the hosting machine.

So I assume you would like to set up a geographic server.

The things you should care about are:

- processing power (CPU), which is needed to create map tiles and/or query data
- RAM, which allows many processes to work in parallel and is linked to CPU
- disk storage is important if you intend to have your server store a large number of tiles (a WMS server)
- bandwidth, necessary to have your tiles served fast

I never used ArcGIS Server nor QGIS Server (I'm using GeoServer) but the above mentioned aspects should anyway be considered.

I would suggest renting a hourly based low performance virtual machine for testing and then eventually upgrade it based on the outcome.

**Update:**

Something I didn't mention before but I think is relevant to the whole question is: "How many concurrent users is the app going to serve?".